# Currently running query inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, dbcc

I have a stored procedure that is currently running, and seems to hang/lock on a specific query. How can i see which query? Preferably without modifying the proc.

Using

```
DBCC Inputbuffer (65)
```

gives me

> Language Event    0   EXEC mySP;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent stored procedure to get extended information on currently running queries. It's available to download from:
http://whoisactive.com

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(st.text, ( r.statement_start_offset / 2 ) + 1, 
              ( ( CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset <= 0
                       THEN DATALENGTH(st.text) 
              ELSE r.statement_end_offset END - 
       r.statement_start_offset ) / 2 ) + 1) AS statement_text 
FROM   sys.dm_exec_requests r 
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) st 
WHERE  session_id = 65
```

Comment: Cool, that seems to work great! (For other people wanting this, change/remove the WHERE-line.)

Comment: Its helpful to add a line WHERE session_id != < this session id >

Comment: @GabrielMcAdams - In the case of the question they are specifically interested in session id `65` (from `DBCC Inputbuffer (65)`)

Comment: @MartinSmith - You're right, and I didn't mean that it would be helpful to the original poster - but to add to his comment here that mentions removing the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL Profiler; as the name suggests, it's the main profiling tool for SQL Server and it can show the execution time for each statement inside a procedure.

Comment: That was my thought as well, but all it shows me is the "EXEC mySP" query used to trigger the SP. Or am I using incorrect filtering?

Comment: @cederlof - You would need to capture the `SP:StmtCompleted` and `SP:StmtStarting` events in Profiler.