# What exactly is SQL Server stuck on?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a long running query in SQL Server 2014. It's a stored procedure invocation. In Activity Monitor, it shows up. The details view provides the currently running SQL, which is the EXEC statement. The command column says it's an `UPDATE`.

The stored procedure in question has several `UPDATE` statements. How do I know which one is currently running? Also, is there a way to know the stored procedure parameters?

Comment: First part is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9293429/73226. Second part not whilst it's already running except if the plan in plan cache was compiled for this execution and then you can get them from the XML.

Comment: sp_who2, sp_whoIsActive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long to comment and thought it doesn't answer you question, it may give you some places to start.

1. Kill the proc, then use SQL Profiler to trace the proc while you execute it. **This is resource intensive though** and option 2 is better IMHO.
2. Use Adam Machanic's [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com) to trouble shoot. There are lots of tutorials out there with different options and use cases for this. A popular one is:

`exec dbo.sp_WhoIsActive @get_plans =1, @get_additional_info = 1`