How can I determine what TSQL code is executing on a blocked thread
We're chasing a repeated blocking/deadlock problem with a vendor's product, and I'm trying to get some clues to help point their development team as to what the issue might be.  I'm currently using     sys.dm_exec_sql_text to try and determine the executing sql on blocked threads, but it seems that returns either the entire batch text, or the last executed statement.
Does anyone have some methods to determine exactly what statement is currently executing on the thread?

Check sys.dm_exec_requests, the are start and end columns (statement_start_offset, statement_end_offset) for the code current running

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39624020/what-exactly-is-sql-server-stuck-on

Deadlocks don't block ... In fact they terminate one process quickly.
